# Grep for a regular expression in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector of character strings which I need to grep through.

The term I would like to grep is "A-10", but I would like it only to pick up rows where "A-10" is an independent word (e.g. "A-10 aircraft maintenance" and NOT "WQDA-10-ASP").

Which regular expression(s) would allow me to grep for "A-10" as an separate word and not part of a different word or string?

Comment: How about using `"A-10 "` instead of `"A-10"` (added space)?

Comment: Thanks, @David, but I've found that adding arbitrary spaces to grep terms in R can get messy and hard to keep track of (I've got over 100 sets of terms to grep over 8 million observations).

Comment: @Austin Good catch; sorry about that. I guess `\\b` cannot do the job, so I will delete my answer (as soon as I can). I would do what's show in Dunder Chief's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
abc <- c('A-10 maintanance', 'WQDA-10-ASP')
grep('(^|\\s)A-10($|\\s)', abc)
```

where `(^|\\s)` means beginning of string or whitespace, and `($|\\s)` means end of line or whitespace

Also take a look at the `stringr` package if you want some nice regex functions.

Comment: Thanks @DunderChief, this seems to have worked -- thanks for the explanation as well and suggestion to check out stringr

Comment: '(^|\\s)A-10($|\\s)' excludes observations like -A-10-, even though this regex is a bit clunkier. Thanks, @DunderChief!